# Automate\Control Spofity remotely

Tags: spotify

I am looking for a way to automate Spotify, either through controlling the desktop application or through an API that will allow me to access the data directly. What I am wanting to do is send commands that will control the play of music. I know I can do this through web automation, but are there any other ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Spotify Connect API to control playback on Spotify. You can read more about them [here](https://developer.spotify.com/news-stories/2017/04/10/new-endpoints-beta-web-api-connect/) and the documentation is [here](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/web-api-connect-endpoint-reference/).